# plt.show() blocks in matplotlib 1.3

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, blocking

I am essentially writing a program that fits a spline to the points I click on a matplotlib window. I am using the `LineBuilder` class given as an example on the matplotlib website (code below, comments explain code that I have inserted). However, I want to exit the plot when I click on a certain region of the plotting window. The code I have works on one computer (matplotlib 1.2 I believe). On another computer (matplotlib 1.3) it does not continue the code that follows `plt.show()` after I click the appropriate part of the window. Instead, when I quit my GUI, it then decides to run the code that follows `plt.show()`.

Does anybody know what might cause this? I'm not sure the exact nature of this problem. I do know that if I turn `block=False` in `plt.show()`, the code will run but I cannot build my line, so I have a feeling it might be related to this. But I can't find if that has changed. Code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line): 
        self.line = line
        self.xs = list(line.get_xdata())
        self.ys = list(line.get_ydata()) 
        self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self) 
    def __call__(self, event):
        print 'click', event
        if event.inaxes!=self.line.axes: return 
        self.xs.append(event.xdata)
        self.ys.append(event.ydata) 
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys) 
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw()
        #If x.data < previous, plt.close ('all')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click to build line segments')
line, = ax.plot([0], [0])
linebuilder = LineBuilder(line)
plt.show ()
#Code that follows does not run in newer (?) version
```

Comment: Do you have an error message to do with this?

Comment: Please try with 1.4.1 or 1.4.2.  This behaviour was reverted.

Comment: @matsjoyce - No error messages.

Comment: @tcaswell - Yes, it goes away with 1.4.1. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib has an interactive and a non-interactive mode, and I've found as well that depending on system configuration or even how you launch your scipt (system shell, interactive shell, dedicated shell, IDLE shell...) this may be different.

If you call `matplotlib.interactive(True)` somewhere at the beginning of your code, this should be avoided. It worked for me in Matplotlib 0.99 and 1.3.1, on python 2.65 and 2.75 respectively. `plt.ion()` is also supposed to switch modes though I haven't tested it.